# Replying to Teams message in channel after a specific keyword posting

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Trying to understand what would be the right configuration to reply to a message when someone posts a specific keywords in a Teams channel.

**Scenario:**

1. Keyword is messaged to Teams channel
2. Logic App sends out a specific information from Dynatrace as the reply
3. This should be sort of switch statement because I want to be able to implement different scenarios and send out different configuration information from Dynatrace upon a specific keyword

**What has been done:**

[logic app configuration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAjVD.png)

[logic app configuration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sczH.png)

The error message I am getting when Logic App has been triggered:

[logic app execution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFGfn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out by actually assigning the keyword to a variable as a string and then switch statement is checking that keyword, and it did well for me.